# Searching for overlaps of subjects between two studies

Tags: linux, excel, terminal

I'm trying to see if these two studies have some of the same subjects. Their identification numbers are different, so I'm checking manually if any subjects have the same age, gender, health problems, etc. Is there a way I can check for matches in several categories between two excel sheets? This might be basic, sorry; I'm still new to terminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have the sheets in CSV format and with the same column order to make programmatical comparing easier. I recommend writing a Python script for this task. Something like this:

```
with open("file1.csv","r") as f:
  data1=[line.strip().split(",") for line in f.readlines()]

with open("file2.csv","r") as f:
  data2=[line.strip().split(",") for line in f.readlines()]

intersections = [x for x in data1 if x in data2]
print(repr(intersections))
```

The `intersections` array will contain lines which are the exact same in both files.

Comment: If working with Python, CSV isn't necessary -- there are excellent libraries for parsing both .xls and .xlsx formats natively.